# Can a character operate their weapon through both an MIU and an MIU Weapon Interface?

Tags: dark-heresy-2e

A 'Good Craftsmanship' MIU:

> grants a +10 bonus to commune with machine spirits and for Tech-Use,
>   Operate, Logic, Inquiry, and **Ballistic Skill** tests made as part of
>   interfacing with the MIU systems

and the MIU Weapon Interface:

> is more simplified, allowing the user to remotely operate a single
>   weapon which is attached user’s body. While not as elaborate, it is
>   easier to use and a favourite of many militant professions. This
>   system allows the user to fire the linked ranged weapon as a Free
>   Action during his turn.

My question is, can a character have both of the above and be able to fire his linked weapon as a Free Action with a +10 bonus to his Ballistic Skill?

The handbook errata on a related query:

> **Q:** Can a heavy weapon be mounted with a Mind Impulse Unit (MIU) or MIU
>   Weapon Interface (page 184)?
>
> **A:** Answer: Yes, though the user would have to perform the Brace Heavy
>   Weapon action as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

*Core Rule Book page 184*

> **Mind Impulse unit (MIU)**
>
> *[fluff snip]* Common
>   models impose no modifiers to machine spirit
>   communication, and add a +10 bonus to Tech-Use or Operate
>   tests used in conjunction with devices capable of MIU linking.
>
> *[poor models details]*
>
> • Good models grant a +10 bonus to commune with machine
>   spirits and for Tech-Use, Operate, Logic, Inquiry, and Ballistic
>   Skill tests made as part of interfacing with the MIU systems.
>
> **MIU Weapon interface**
>
> *[fluff snip]* allowing the user to remotely operate a single weapon which is
>   attached user’s body. While not as elaborate, it is easier to use and
>   a favourite of many militant professions.
>   This system allows the user to fire the linked ranged weapon
>   as a Free Action during his turn. ***Note that he can still only take
>   a single Action with the Attack subtype during his turn***. This
>   additional weapon must be connected to the user via the MIU
>   weapon interface, and is usually equipped as a shoulder mount.

There is nothing in the item description that prevents the "Attack as a Free Action" and the "+10 Bonus" from stacking, the only qualification provided is to state that you can still only perform one attack action per turn. So lets break down the properties to see if there's any conflicts.

An Attack is either a Ballistics Skill (Ranged) or Weapon Skill (Melee) Test and is a Half Action

The MIU allows you to attack with the connected ranged weapon as a Free Action instead.

The Craftsmanship of the MIU confers a +10 bonus to Ballistics Skill tests.

Bonuses stack, they don't counteract. As evidenced by the example on page 226

> Arbitrator Kol Merlow wants to use a Standard Attack action to
>   shoot his autogun at a suspected cultist. Merlow’s Ballistic Skill is
>   45 and he is at Short range, which grants him a +10 bonus. Merlow
>   spends a Half Action to Aim, granting him another +10 bonus. In
>   addition, the Standard Attack confers a +10 bonus to the attack roll.
>   However, there is a very heavy mist in the underhive area, so Merlow
>   suffers a –20 penalty as he tries to spot his target through the fog.
>   After all bonuses and penalties have been combined, Merlow needs
>   to roll 55 or less on his Ballistic Skill test to hit the cultist (45 + 10 +
>   10 + 10 – 20 = 55).